# Grid with usercontrols templates in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in WPF and try learn VMMV. I try to create TabControl with template for content in xaml.
I want tabitem with content of grid and in grid list of usercontrols. After adding a usercontrol the header of tabitem render right but nothing is in content. What is wrong?

This is my xaml:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Hidden" Name="tcContent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class Tab
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserControl> Content { get; set; }
}

public class MainWindowsViewModel
{        
    ObservableCollection<Tab> _items = new ObservableCollection<Tab>();

    public ObservableCollection<Tab> Items
    {
         get
         {
              return _items;
         }
    }       
}
```

Behind code for fill tabcontrol:

```
public MainWindow()
{ 
     this.DataContext = new MainWindowsViewModel();
}

public void AddToTab(string header, UserControl c)
{
     Tab tab = new Tab();
     tab.Header = header;
     tab.Content = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();
     tab.Content.Add(c);

     ((MainWindowsViewModel)this.DataContext).Items.Add(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the MVVM principle.

In your view-model, you have a collection of the `Tab` objects, and each of them holds a collection of `UserControl`s. In this way, your view-model contains some view elements (`UserControl`s). In MVVM, you shouldn't do that.

Instead, you create the view-models for each tab item that describe a **model of the representation** (hence view-*model*); and in XAML, you describe how do these **view-models** should look like using `DataTemplate`s.

But this is all required only if your views have to be dynamic. E.g. you don't know which data will be available because you're fetching them from a database.

If your `TabItem`s display a set of `UserControl`s that won't change, then just describe your view completely in XAML, without any `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: I think I undranstand. With my minimum knowlinge of languagne :) I need one view model for one tabitem. No all tab items in one class.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, remove `Visibility="Hidden"` form the `TabControl`. Then change the `ControlControl` to `ItemsControl` which can hold `Tab.Content`, which is a collection. However, you should pay attention to the problems mentioned in @dymanoid's answer.

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the rest of my code. This property I change in code later. But this is not the point of view.